# jQuery animate() doesn't work, but css() does

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am creating some sliding panels (accordion) and I want to slide the background image so that a piece of the background is always showing. I am having problems animating the panels, but css works fine. e.g.:

```
if(slideIndex == index) {
    $this.children('.heading').children().children().fadeIn(settings.slideSpeed);
    $this.children('.heading').animate({height: 250});
} else {
    $this.children('.heading').children().children().not('.panel-strip').fadeOut(settings.slideSpeed);
    $this.children('.heading').animate({height: 500});
}
```

Doesn't work, but if I substitute in `css` instead of `animate` it works.

The HTML is `<div class="panels-background heading">` that I am trying to access.

The javascript is adapted from [liteAccordion](http://nicolahibbert.com/demo/liteAccordion/).

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/beaverusiv/GGd38/4/ search for 'CODE' in the javascript for the pertinent area.

Comment: `$this.children('.heading').children().children().not('.panel-strip')` ... mmm ... there must be a better selector

Comment: If you can find one, gold star :)

Comment: There is no `CODE` keyword in the fiddle you posted. Please tell us what element's background you are animating or at least some background on how this works. There are 375 lines of code there.

Comment: Updated. Hopefully more clear. I've tried cutting down the javascript but it never works when I do...

Comment: @mrtsherman: There *is* in fact a comment `//CODE` right above the relevant parts of the code in the javascript window (Chrome could find it with Ctrl+F...). If you scroll from the bottom you'll find it pretty quickly.

Comment: Don't you have to have a time with the animation? .animate({height: 500}, 2000); ?

Comment: @BeaverusIV - well it has the marker once you edited your question and updated with the correct link. I am well aware of ctrl-f on a webpage.

Comment: @mikevoermans - duration is optional, see the jQuery api http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is right below that code block where you are calling:

```
$this
     .children('.heading')
     .stop(true)
     .animate({
          left : (side ? 0 : slideWidth) + slideIndex * settings.headerWidth
      }, 
     settings.slideSpeed, 
     settings.easing,
     function() { 
         // flag ensures that fn is only called one time per triggerSlide
         if (!core.slideAnimCompleteFlag) {
             settings.onSlideAnimComplete.call(next);
             core.slideAnimCompleteFlag = true;
         }
     });
```

When you call `.stop()` it is stopping the height animation that you are trying to call before.

Comment: THANK YOU. Now I need to try fiddle with the animations to get them running smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem once; it seemed animate property wont function as proposed when using just jQuery. Had a little research, added jQuery UI library just by hunch. And it worked. At the end, I included jQuery UI Effect library file and it worked like hell.

At documentation(http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/animate) it says that UI effect library extends animate function to support colors but for me it helped in height animation too. dunno why..

For downloading this goto http://jqueryui.com/download choose Core and UI effects at bottom. Leave rest unchecked(if you want to recieve solution in just around 8kb file). Then you will recieve a zip file as a download.

In this zip, goto js directory; pick the file with name something like jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js and include that in your page. I think this will do. again you get to add cooler effects like slide,box, explode etc.. I guess you dont need further instructions.. gud day :)